# How can I prevent xorg.conf from being overwritten

Tags: xorg

Every once in a while, my `xorg.conf` is being replaced and my original `xorg.conf` is being backed up to `xorg.conf.MMDDYYYY`.

```
xorg.conf.04202014
xorg.conf.04262014
xorg.conf.05132014
xorg.conf.05212014
xorg.conf.06222014
xorg.conf.07012014
xorg.conf.07072014
```

That's 7 times that it has happened over the last 4 months. I assume it happens after x gets upgraded.

How can i stop this from happening?

It would be ideal if apt-get (if it's what's doing this) would prompt me showing me a diff of the old and new `xorg.conf` instead of just silently replacing my `xorg.conf`.

Comment: The default behaviour of apt is to prompt you about any conflicts in configuration files. And I don't think `xorg.conf` is part of any package. Further, backups created by apt don't use just dates as extensions. So I strongly doubt apt is doing this. Do you have a graphics card, with some accompanying management software?

Comment: muru: I have nvidia-settings installed, but I dont run nvidia-settings by myself, 100% sure I didn't run it for atleast a month, yet it has happened twice this month already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behavior on 4 of my desktop machines. It appears to be related to this Bug report, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1310489. IMHO many machines are probably suffering this Bug, All of mine are. I suggest signing on to the Bug report.